# CSS how do I define the height between multiple label and textboxes elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

If for example I want to have 2 rows of 6 textboxes and 1 initial row of textboxes how using CSS do I define the height/space between the textboxes so they are consistently spaced.

Or should I just use a table?

Comment: You can use 'padding' for equal spacing..

Comment: Use tables and set height to td's

Comment: @dotNETbeginner wouldn't padding define the area inside each element http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: @sayth: padding inside table or margin for controls..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g4CWC/34/

For each textbox provide css with same margin, For instance:

```
.textbox { margin:10px }
```

You can add all the textboxes in a `<div>` and provide css as

```
div{margin:auto;}
```

Now If you resize the window spaces between the text box will remain the same.

Comment: The JSFiddle ends up with 3 columns and 2 rows, how is that defined in the fidddle.

Comment: @sayth: its the `width` of `<div>` given in css which binds the textboxes to 3 columns and 2 rows.